# How many conformations are possible for ethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, conformers

I am talking on the basis of observations made on the Newman projection of ethane.

According, to the various sources, that I found on many websites, the number of conformational isomers are 2. They are the *gauche* form and the *staggered* form, but according to the book I have there are three conformations. They are accounting for the *inverted gauche* form separately.

I am quite doubtful about it. By *inverted gauche*, I am talking about the gauche structure formed, by rotating the Newman projection structure by 180° degrees, along the sigma bond.

Comment: Ethane does not have a gauche form. The form which is neither skew nor staggered is called eclipsed.

Answer (score 3):

> How many conformations are possible for ethane?

It's the same like asking, "How many angles are possible between 0 and 2π?"

The answer is infinite!

Every slightly change in the rotational angle yields a new conformer. It's only makes sense to ask how many special conformers are possible for ethane. Special in the sense of them being recognised by a specific name.

Two types of conformers are named in case of ethane; staggered and eclipsed. **Gauche form is *not* defined for ethane.** You need unsymmetric substitutes on the carbon on either side of the bond being studied, like in propane.

The staggered conformer:
[image: Staggered conformer of ethane]

The eclipsed conformer:
[image: Eclipsed conformer of ethane]

Now in a full 2π rotation you will encounter both the staggered and the eclipsed form 3 times each, alternating every π/3 radians. But as all the substituents are hydrogen in ethane's case, all staggered and eclipsed form are equivalent respectively.

An excerpt from *Conformations of Ethane<sup>[[1]](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/67072)</sup>*:

> This process can be continued all around the 360°circle, with three possible eclipsed conformations and three staggered conformations, in addition to an infinite number of variations in between.

So to answer your question:

There are infinite conformers of ethane, out of which two are named and each of the named conformer is encountered three times during a full 2π rotation.

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/67072) Conformations of Ethane

https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/67072 (accessed Jun 26, 2021).</sup>

Comment: yea I thought so too, but the answer provided is 3 ..that was the reason for my confusion...anyways thanks.. but if anyone has the reason for having three different conformations for ethane.. please do suggest

Comment: @sujayvivek Are you sure that ethane was the molecule in question.